# Code not working in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that works perfectly in Chrome, but the CSS does not work in Edge and the scrolling text does not work in IE10.

See how it should work in Chrome (please allow about 5 seconds for the scrolling text to start:

https://jsfiddle.net/oxw4e5yh/

CSS:

```
<style>
/* Make it a marquee */

.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    font: 50px'Verdana';
}
.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    animation: marquee linear infinite;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0px;
}
/* Make it move */

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate(10%, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
}
/* Make it pretty */

.scroll {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    position: fixed;
    font: 50px'Verdana';
    bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    left: 0px;
    height: 10%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your CSS doesn't work in Edge is because of the `font` declaration. There is a space missing. Change inside `.marquee`:

```
font: 50px Verdana;
```

The reason it doesn't work in IE10/IE11 is that the `animationDuration` property is not supported in `JavaScript`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animationduration.asp)

If you want to make it work though, you should remove the `animation: marquee linear infite;` from the `css` and add it to the `JavaScript`:

*CSS*

```
.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

*JS*

```
spanSelector[i].style.animation = "marquee linear infinite " + timeTaken + "s";
```

Now it should work in IE10/IE11 :)

Comment: I changed the `font` in `..marquee` and it works in Edge, but not IE. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i am sorry. Inside `.marguee`. In IE10/IE11 changing the `animationDuration` of an element using `JavaScript` is not supported

Comment: @Wienievra Updated answer

Comment: So I replace `spanSelector[i].style.animationDuration = timeTaken + "s";` with `spanSelector[i].style.animation = "marquee linear infinite " + timeTaken + "s";`?

Comment: @Wienievra Exactly :)